# Interrupt routines microchip

Tags: interrupt, pic, microchip

I'm doing an speed controller project at University, so, I've had some problems with interrupt routines, I can't find one routine to DIV0Error, SFTACError, COVBError, COVAError, OVBError, OVAError, DAE, DOOVR and SGHT. When I try build this routines, the compiler said that the p33EP256MC502 don't have support for this. How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the names of those interrupt routines from?

Comment: There are some routines on compiler folder (.gld archive), but I can't find interrupt routines for this cases. I'm using xc16 v1.32.